# Cassandra - dynamic schema design to avoid tombstones

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql

I'm writing an application that needs to keep track of "objects". Specifically, when an "object" (a 1k blob) arrives at the application level it is persisted in C* for future uses. Speaking about numbers, I expect to get 10-50 billion *distinct* objects, so expected data size is between 10-50TB.

The application can see the exact same object multiple times during a variable time window (eg a day, or a month). The application "consumes" these objects when some conditions apply (they are not consumed immediately), so a counter at application level is associated to each object. I cannot tolerate under/over counting, so C* counters are a big no, and I rely on proper "locking" at application level. I'm basically ensuring that each object is properly counted, hitting the "right" amount of "global locks" and penalties, but I'm fine with that.  When the application finishes to process one object, the associated counter reaches zero and I'm sure this object will never be used anymore, so it can be safely deleted (from the application point of view).

However, the problem is that I've absolutely no guarantees that:

1. If object X was seen 5 times in a month then all these 5 objects will be processed all in a row.
2. If object X was seen 5 times in a month then this object will be processed 5 times all in a row.

Really, both statements are the same thing: I cannot reduce the processing to a *queue*, a *classic Cassandra anti-pattern*, because the counter won't go to zero immediately.

Indeed, these 5 objects will be (more realistically) processed one at time with some undetermined delay in-between. So if object X have 5 "counts", when one object X gets processed I must update the counter and set it to 4, and "wait" until all the remaining 4 objects X are processed, one at time.

This is the worst "hybrid" model I've seen so far, in the sense that it takes the worst of two worlds: the *frequently updated columns* model, and the *queue* anti-pattern model.

I'd like to delete all these objects to reclaim storage space, and I'm trying to find a model that won't suffer *too much* the write pattern of the application.

---

From what I've seen so far, if I could find a way to collect objects in a table that could be dropped at the end, I would perform only frequent updates because a drop would delete the table completely and avoid all the deletes and the tombstones mess (assuming no snapshots are taken when dropping a table). I would then create a new table for processing the next bunch of data (something like a constant table name followed by a increasing monotone number to avoid reusing the same table name over time, e.g `TBLNAME0`, `TBLNAME1`, etc..).

This would bring obviously some benefits to the application, but it would introduce some potential inconsistencies in the schema. Thinking about a distributed thing, if one or more nodes are down I'd get high chanches of messing up data, and obviously this is something I'd like to avoid.

On the other hand, if I don't drop an entire table and I stick with deletes, the tombstones could give huge read penalties to the application.

Speaking about delete/drop frequencies, I'd expect to drop a table once per day or two on average, and I'd expect more than 10M deletes per day regularly.

---

**Q1: To drop or not to drop?** (I vote for drop).

**Q2: Is really Cassandra a good fit for this? Any suggestion on what else to use?**

Answer (score 1):

> ...I expect to get 10-50 billion distinct objects, so expected data size
>   is between 10-50TB...

With this big dataset, how would you be able to reshuffle data to new table in any decent timeframe?

I recommend that you delete objects. If these tombstones are not in a wide row, then read penalty to get live cells won't be as much. So creating table with sensible partition key would definitely be plus.

From my experience, for frequently updating columns, increasing commitlog_total_space_in_mb and memtable_total_space_in_mb helps by avoiding frequent memtable to sstable flushes. That reduces compaction and gc pressure.

If you provided more detail on proposed schema and example of most frequent CQL statements you expect to execute, people might get better picture of what you are intending to do.

Comment: I don't expect to reuse any data,so no data shuffling or whatsoever.I don't have wide rows already,but the freq update means tombstones will be harder to remove because they will lie on different sstables.I don't understand why having a "large" commitlog space could reduce flushes and compactions because usually the `memtable_total_space_in_mb` is the bottleneck.

Comment: Because if data that has not been flushed from memtable to disk exceeds available commitlog space, memtable must be flushed. Even when memtable itself might not have reached the limit. This is to make sure data is commited to sstable before commitlog space is reused.

Comment: Yes I know, but `memtable_total_space_in_mb` is the real bottleneck , not the commitlog space. A 300GB of commitlog space (very common IMHO) is huge compared to a (rare) 30GB of memtable total space. Don't you agree?

Comment: I absolutely agree with that. But I didn't know that your node had that (or in some ratio there of) setting. But in the essence of my comment was, to try and reduce flush from memtable to sstable for frequently updating columns use case.